# The destination does not support the architecture for which the selected software is built

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, shared-libraries, target

Today I was creating a shared library in a project containing multiple targets where I first had only one (and no shared lib) when all of a sudden my project produced the following error when trying to run.

"The destination does not support the architecture for which the selected software is built. Switch to a destination that supports that architecture in order to run the selected software."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through all the suggested steps here on Stackoverflow to no avail I found the answer to be a very simple one ...

I forgot to include the main.m in the targets so an executable would not be built. Adding the appropriate main files to their targets solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do not change the bundle name and the Executable file in `info.plist`. I changed them and got this error. After I changed them to default, the error's gone.

Comment: Thank you, this did it for me. I also had to delete deriveddata and restart XCode.

Answer (score 0):

[The selected destination does not support the architecture](http://blog.csdn.net/sniffer12345/article/details/8016153), 
  maybe can help you. I have release the question by the way.

Comment: I would also comment on what the link is about and include a bit more detail in the body of an answer. Links can change. Some context would be useful!

Answer (score 0):

Select Info.plist in your project navigator tree and make sure it is not assigned to a target. I have confirmed this is the correct solution.